# How to getget list of wifi newtorks in .Net Maui

Tags: wifi, maui

How can I get a list of wifi networks in .NEt Maui?

I tried to use Wifimanager but I get a warning of obsolete.

Thanks

Comment: which platform do you use?

Comment: Did you mean wifiManager.startScan()" is deprecated?

Comment: You could refer to this thread : [WifiManager startScan deprecated. Alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56401057/wifimanager-startscan-deprecated-alternative)